# Why is my ByteToMessageDecoder decode method never called?

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to get to grips with Netty. I'm using HTTP for my example here (I know there are HTTP (de/en)coders in the library but the point of this exercise for me is to get my head around how the pipeline operates.

I have a simple pipeline constructed as follows

```
b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
  @Override
  protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel){
    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new Announcer());
    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new Receiver());
    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new Source());
  }
});
```

Announcer is a `MessageToByteEncoder<String>` with an `encode` method:

```
@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg, ByteBuf out) {
  byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII);
  out.writeBytes(bytes);
}
```

Source is a `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` with a `read` method:

```
@Override
public void read(ChannelHanderContext ctx) {
  String path = "/";
  String host = "xkcd.com"
  String content = "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\n" +
    "Host: " + host + "\n" +
    "\n";
  ctx.writeAndFlush(content);
}
```

Receiver is a `ByteToMessageDecoder` with a `decode` method:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
    String e = in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    System.err.println(e);
    out.add(e);
}
```

I've verified that the output of Source is a valid HTTP request and gets a response from xkcd.com:80

I see Source and then Announcer's methods called to generate the request but **I never see the Receiver's decode method called**.

Why?

Comment: Could it be that you're checking/debugging class `Receiver` but your code actually uses `Receiever`?

Comment: Oops, that's just a typo in the question. Real code has same spelling for both. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a decoder implementation

> You’ll find that for inbound data the `channelRead` method/event is overridden. This method is called for each message that’s read from  the inbound Channel . It will then call the `decode()` method of the  provided decoder and forward the decoded bytes to the next  `ChannelInboundHandler` in the pipeline.

In your case you have overridden the `read` method of a `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` and you are not calling         `ctx.read()` inside this method. This means it will prevent the calling of the `channelRead` method of any `ChannelInboundHandler` and hence the `decode` method of any decoder. In your case `Source` class is preventing reading from a channel. 
Also the purpose of overriding the read method of a `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` should not be to write something to the channel.

Following is the definition of the read method.

> **`read(ChannelHandlerContext)`** Invoked on request to read more data from the Channel

You could read [Netty in action](https://www.manning.com/books/netty-in-action) book for better understanding of netty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will look into it today. Q: how should I be sending the message? Just on the channel object directly or it's correct to have something in the pipeline I've just used the wrong method?

Comment: You can  write in the `channelActive` method of a `ChannelInboundHandler`